# UITableViewCell loading incorrect image after reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that populates its cells with data from firebase. Each cell posses an image and each image is loaded asynchronously and cached. The **problem** is that random cells will use the wrong image, although the other data in the cell is correct. If I scroll so that the cell goes off view, the correct image then loads.

**Research**:

[Images in UITableViewCells are loading wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686516/images-in-uitableviewcells-are-loading-wrong) (Dont really understand Obj C)

[What is the correct way to use prepareForReuse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773208/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-prepareforreuse)

**Image Cache:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCache(urlString: String) {
        self.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo3")

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            })

        }).resume()



    }

}
```

**Tableview Cell**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class GroupCell: UITableViewCell {

    var group: Groups!
    var members = [String]()


    @IBOutlet weak var groupImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var groupName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var groupRep: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var memberCount: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }


    func configureCell(group: Groups) {
        self.group = group

        self.groupName.text = group.name
        self.groupRep.text = "\(group.groupScore)"

        if let groupImage = group.groupImage {
            self.groupImage.loadImageUsingCache(urlString: groupImage)

        } else {
            self.groupImage.image = //random image
        }

        for member in group.members {
            self.members.append(member.key)

        }
         self.memberCount.text = "\(members.count)"
    }
}
```

**TableView**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell") as? GroupCell {
            let group = FriendSystem.system.activeGroups[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(group: group)

            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use something like KingFisher to make your life easier. https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Images change to wrong images while scrolling after async image loading to a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958826/swift-images-change-to-wrong-images-while-scrolling-after-async-image-loading-to)

Comment: Used Kingfisher and life is good. Thanks for the reccomendation

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to add the `prepareForReuse` method to your GroupCell class.

In that method add `self.groupImage.image = nil` It will reset your image view to empty until the correct image is set.

Comment: I actually had implemented this code prior without success. It was apart of one of the threads I mentioned